# prove if a sequence is convergent to 1 then its squared root is also convergent to 1

Tags: real-analysis, limits

prove that if the sequence $S_n$ converges to 1, then $S_n^\frac{1}{2}$ converges to 1.

Let $\epsilon>0.$
$|\sqrt{S_n}-1|=|\sqrt{S_n}-1|.\frac{|\sqrt{S_n}+1|}{|\sqrt{S_n}+1|}=\frac{|S_n-1|}{\sqrt{S_n}+1}<\frac{|S_n|+1}{\sqrt{S_n}+1}\overset{?}{<}\epsilon$
I Think I should find an $N\in \natural$ such that for $n>N$ we can have $|\sqrt{S_n}-1|<\epsilon $
I am learning and yet not really confident about the whole limit definition. How should I keep on proving the statement of this question? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $1/(\sqrt{S_n}+1)$ can be bounded for large enough $n$ and $|S_n-1|$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: More precisely: $S_n>\frac 14$ for $n$ large (why?). So, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{S_n}+1}\le\frac{1}{3/2} = \frac 23$ for these $n$.

Comment: So... you haven't learned that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = L$ and $f$ is a continuous function that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n)= f(L)$?  Or that $\sqrt{}:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ is a continuous function?

Answer (score 1):

For any arbitrarily small $\epsilon > 0$:

As $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small we can assume our choice of $\epsilon < 1$.  (If our result is true for our small choice it will be true for any larger choice;  [hence we picked an $\epsilon \ge 1$ we can just use an $\epsilon'$ so that $0 < \epsilon' < 1\le \epsilon$] but the larger choices aren't relevant and limits are about behavior as arbitrarily *small* values.)

And so $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Therefore $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$.  $-2\epsilon + \epsilon^2< -2\epsilon + \epsilon =-\epsilon$

The definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = 1$ means we can find an $N$ so that when $n > N$ we know that $

$|S_n -1| < \epsilon$

So $-\epsilon < S_n - 1< \epsilon$

$1-\epsilon < S_n < 1+ \epsilon$.

so $0 \le (1-\epsilon)^2 = 1-2\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < 1-\epsilon < S_n < 1+\epsilon < 1+2\epsilon + \epsilon^2= (1+\epsilon)^2$

So $1-\epsilon < \sqrt{S_n} < 1+\epsilon$

$-\epsilon < \sqrt{S_n} - 1 < \epsilon$

So $|\sqrt{S_n} -1| < \epsilon$ if $n > N$.

So $\sqrt{S_n}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had seen several proofs for this question. Yours is my favourite. I just am little bit confused why do we have to choose two epsilons? why do we need $\epsilon_1$

Comment: We don't really.  We have to prove the result for *any* $\epsilon>0$.  This proof assumes $0<\epsilon < 1$.  So invariable someone will ask "what if $\epsilon \ge 1$?" Well, we are concerned with showing this is true for arbitrarily *small* values.  If we can prove it is true for arbitrarily small values then specific values aren't relevant and will "take care of themselves".  So I avoid the issue by saying "If I can prove it for an epsilon less than yours then it is true for yours".